# outgoing call answered in PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I am detecting an outgoing call in android, but i want to know when the phone call was answered.

I have an `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` receiver which gives me the phone number that the user dialed.

I also use `PhoneStateListener` which gives me the call state [much like this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And)
so i use the stated `CALL_STATE_RINGING`, `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` and `CALL_STATE_IDLE`

To identify incoming call: first i get `CALL_STATE_RINGING`, then only if the call was answered - I get `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` finally i get `CALL_STATE_IDLE`.

but on outgoing call i always get `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`,then `CALL_STATE_IDLE`- no matter if the call was answered or not...

So how can i know if / when the outgoing call was answered ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot get the ringing state into the outgoing call.Its directly call the offhook state whenever their is outgoing call placed

Comment: yes, that i figured out.
but maybe there is another way? some intent to catch?
i also tried to look at the call log (android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI), but it seams that it is updated sometime after i get the CALL_STATE_IDLE....

Answer (score 2):

ok, i managed to have some kind of a solution:

when i get the CALL_STATE_IDLE - i schedule a timer for 500 ms repeatedly, and check the android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI

i search for the last phone call made from the outgoing phone number, and once i found it - i can get the duration.

it usually takes about 300 - 700 ms to get it, so i have 0.5 - 1 sec delay...